# How to enable Autowired for FeignClient in JHipster?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

I have a microservice application and i want to enable it to call API.

**FeignClientConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "blabla")
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
}
```

And then spring boot App :

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude ={MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class,MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class, ApplicationProperties.class})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MyApp { }
```

**The feign client**

```
@FeignClient()
public interface ExtClient { ... }
```

I then tried to autowired the client

**Mytransaction.java**

```
public class MyTransaction {
@Autowired
ExtClient txnClient;
 ....
}
```

But it fails with a NPE. How to autowired FEIGN in JHipster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyTransaction` must be a Spring bean. Simplest way is to annotate it with `@Service`, this way it'll get instantiated by Spring and `txnClient` will get injected. By the way, you should consider using constructor injection rather than field injection, many examples in JHipster generated code.

Comment: it doesnt work for me. Should i add something to the *.yml ?

Comment: No. Have you checked that the java package of MyTransaction is covered by component scanning settings?